# Simple toggle functionality

Tags: android

### I have achieved this task already with tab , radio button

**But i want to implement it with switch button..... How to do it**

- Any ideas on how to implement this

[image]

**tabs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <include layout="@layout/tabs"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Screen1.java**

```
public class Screen1 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

    }
}
```

**Screen2.java**

```
public class Screen2 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

### Any Ideas .... on how to achieve this !

Comment: use the state of the toggle button and setContentViews accordingly in one activity itself.

Comment: @ Dhara Shah .....Can u show it in code as answer .... It will help me understand it better with my code !

Answer (score 0):

well i havent used the togglebutton  but a simple button and tried to achieve the same 
...here is my code...lets see if that could help you

My Main Activity

```
Button screenswitch;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    screenswitch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    screenswitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            Intent help = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(help);
        }
    });
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Screeen 2" />
```

My SecondActivity

```
Button screenswitch;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    screenswitch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    screenswitch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            Intent help = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(help);
        }
    });
}
```

second.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Screen 1" />
```

and dont forget to declare the new activity in your manifest file .

Comment: yes .... but i am trying to achieve the functionality like a tab ... using button ..... where activities are loaded on the main screen based on selection ... any ideas !